# SQL Join or SUM is returning too many values when working with Redshift database

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift

I'm working with a Redshift database and I can't understand why my join or SUM is bringing too many values. My query is below:

```
SELECT 
    date(u.created_at) AS date,
    count(distinct c.user_id) AS active_users,
    sum(distinct insights.spend) AS fbcosts,
    count(c.transaction_amount) AS share_shake_costs,
    round(((sum(distinct insights.spend) + count(c.transaction_amount)) / 
    count(distinct c.user_id)),2) AS cac
FROM 
    dbname.users AS u
LEFT JOIN
    dbname.card_transaction AS c ON c.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN
    facebookads.insights ON date(insights.date_start) = date(u.created_at)
LEFT JOIN
    dbname.card_transaction AS c2 ON date(c2.timestamp) = date(u.created_at)
WHERE 
    c2.vendor_transaction_description ilike '%share%'
    OR c2.vendor_transaction_description ilike '%shake to win%'
GROUP BY 
    date
ORDER BY 
    1 DESC;
```

This query returns the following data:

[image: Table data from query above]

If we look at 2017-02-08, we can see a total of 1298 for "share_shake_costs". However, if I run the same query just on the card_transaction table I get the following results which are correct.

[image]

The query for this second table looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    date(timestamp),
    sum(transaction_amount)
FROM 
    dbname.card_transaction AS c2
WHERE 
    c2.vendor_transaction_description ilike '%share%'
    OR c2.vendor_transaction_description ilike '%shake to win%'
GROUP BY 
    1
ORDER BY 
    1 DESC;
```

I have a feeling that I have a similar issue for my "fbcosts" column. I think it has to do with my join since the SUM should be working fine.

I'm new to Redshift and SQL so perhaps there's a better way of doing this entire query. Is there anything obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: Remove the joins to tables one by one until you find out which join is causing double counting. (there's probably a few)

Comment: Both queries run different aggregates so may not be good comparisons. Please explain schema or table relationships (which are one-to-many?). And why `LEFT JOIN dbname.card_transaction` on `users` twice?

Comment: These join conditions look weird. Seems like you are saying the date/time a transaction was made must equal the creation date of the user record. Odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a table that contains 1:n mapping and when you join over a common clause, that number is being counted  n times.

Let us say one of your tables, `orders` contains `user_id` and the total bill_amount and the other table, `order_details` contains the detail of the sub-items placed by that user_id.

If you do a left join, by definition, `orders.user_id` will join *n times* to `order_details.user_id`, where

```
n = total number of rows in order_details table
```

and would perform the aggregation (sum, count etc) *n* times.

```
+------------------+          +----------------------+
|      orders      |          |    order_details     |
+------------------+          +----------------------+
|amount    user_id |          | user_id       items  |
+------------------+          +----------------------+
| 1000       123   ---------> |   123         apple  |
              +               +----------------------+
              +-------------> |   123         guava  |
              |               +----------------------+
              v-------------> |   123         mango  |
                              +----------------------+

select sum(amount) from orders o left join order_details od 
on o.user_id = od.user_id; // result: 3000

select count(amount) from orders o left join order_details od 
on o.user_id = od.user_id; // result: 3
```

I hope the reason for large count is clear to you now.

PS: Also, always prefer to enclose OR conditions in ().

```
WHERE 
    (c2.vendor_transaction_description ilike '%share%'
    OR c2.vendor_transaction_description ilike '%shake to win%')
```